# Total arena pages for JIT - what does it mean?

Tags: java, android

I am getting logcat output as follows:

```
02-12 20:06:18.515  11470-11470/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3K, 48% free 3188K/6023K, external 7949K/8580K, paused 29ms
02-12 20:06:18.804  11470-11470/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 3189K/6023K, external 13255K/13400K, paused 28ms
02-12 20:06:19.406  11470-11470/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 3189K/6023K, external 14706K/16754K, paused 56ms
02-12 20:06:19.914  11470-11475/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 11
```

What does "Total arena pages for JIT" really mean?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Mystery...**
It interested me too, when I first saw it. So I've performed a little research. =)
For the beginning, let me clarify what is 'JIT'. JIT stands for Just-In-Time compiler (aka dynamic translator). It's a part of dalvik that translates byte code to optimized native code at run time. [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) is a process virtual machine (VM) in Android operating system that executes applications written for Android.
I found from [dalvik sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/) that the string `"Total arena pages for JIT"` can be met only in one class - `Utility` from 'dalvik\vm\compiler'. Here is a short piece of its code:

```cpp
    /* Arena-based malloc for compilation tasks */
    void * dvmCompilerNew(size_t size, bool zero)
    {
        /* edit: some code omitted. */
retry:
        /* Normal case - space is available in the current page */
        if (size + currentArena->bytesAllocated <= currentArena->blockSize) {
            void *ptr;
            ptr = &currentArena->ptr[currentArena->bytesAllocated];
            currentArena->bytesAllocated += size;
            /* edit: some code omitted. */
        } else {                                                      // <0>
            /*
             * See if there are previously allocated arena blocks before the last
             * reset
             */
            /* edit: some code omitted. */

            /* Time to allocate a new arena */
            ArenaMemBlock *newArena = (ArenaMemBlock *)
                malloc(sizeof(ArenaMemBlock) + blockSize);           // <1>
            if (newArena == NULL) {
                ALOGE("Arena allocation failure");
                dvmAbort();
            }
            newArena->blockSize = blockSize;
            newArena->bytesAllocated = 0;
            newArena->next = NULL;
            currentArena->next = newArena;                           // <2>
            currentArena = newArena;
            numArenaBlocks++;
            if (numArenaBlocks > 10)
                ALOGI("Total arena pages for JIT: %d", numArenaBlocks);
            goto retry;
        }
        /* edit: some code omitted. */
    }
```

As you can see, this message appears only if it was allocated more than 10 arena pages per a compiler.

**What actually 'arena' is?**
You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706466/how-does-malloc-work-in-a-multithreaded-environment) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management). In a few words, it is a concept for the memory management in a multithreaded application. Memory is divided into arenas (regions, areas). Each allocation arena has its own lock, so multiple threads don't interfere with each other when they allocate memory concurrently.

**Why did I see this message? Am I the Chosen One?**
No, I don't think so. =) I'm not really sure, but it seems just like an internal warning from the JIT that it has allocated a large number of memory blocks.
Internally this arena-based malloc is built upon a linked list. I.e. each arena is implemented as a linked list of large blocks of memory. The current block (`currentArena`) maintains a pointer to the next free position in the block (`&(currentArena->ptr[currentArena->bytesAllocated])`), and if the block is filled (see <0>), a new one is allocated (see <1>) and added to the list (see <2>).

Comment: Is this in your opinion some sign/clue that we should do better memory management in our code?

Comment: @Ewoks, no, it's not. It seems to me like a compiler's (JIT) warning. It means compiler has allocated much memory during translation of your program to native code. If you have a memory leak, it will manifest itself in crash with `OutOfMemoryException`, and usually after multiple calls to a spoiled procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, uninstalling and reinstalling again your app is a good solution. Works for me!