# OpenMP: good strategies for depth-first search

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am writing a C++ program that does a brute-force search for closed [Knight's tours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight's_tour). The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/jmoy/b727aecea27cb1e7edb9ace7283b301e).

I would like to parallelize this using OpenMP. My problem is to do this in a way that creates a sufficient degree of parallelism. Currently [the relevant portion](https://gist.github.com/jmoy/b727aecea27cb1e7edb9ace7283b301e#file-knights_tour-cc-L52) of my code looks like this

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count) if (depth==4)
  for (size_t i=0;i<g.neighbours[last].size();i++){
    auto n = g.neighbours[last][i];
    // See if n can be used to extend or complete the tour
```

The `if (depth==4)` is my attempt to make sure that not too many parallel tasks are created but on the other hand enough are created to keep all processors busy. Setting `depth==2` does not change the runtime of the program.

This does not seem to be working out. For a 3x12 problem, on my dual-core processor the total CPU time consumed by the OpenMP version is around 130s whereas a single-threaded version without OpenMP takes around 40s of CPU time.

I would appreciate suggestions on how better to use OpenMP or reasons why it is unsuitable for this problem.

UPDATE: Thanks to @Zulan I have a [newer version](https://gist.github.com/jmoy/2151e6d7070a6ce18aa9298fbe050062) using OpenMP tasks with a much faster sequential performance as well as good parallelization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, lets take a super-quick look at where your application spends its time, by using `perf`:

```
perf record ./knights_tour_omp 3 12
perf report

# Overhead  Command          Shared Object        Symbol                                                                                         
# ........  ...............  ...................  .................................................................................................
#
    53.29%  knights_tour_om  libc-2.19.so         [.] malloc                                                                                       
    23.16%  knights_tour_om  libc-2.19.so         [.] _int_free                                                                                    
    10.31%  knights_tour_om  libc-2.19.so         [.] _int_malloc                                                                                  
     4.78%  knights_tour_om  knights_tour_omp     [.] _Z13continue_tourIZ4mainEUlRKSt6vectorIiSaIiEEE_EmRK5GraphS4_RKS0_IcSaIcEEiiRT_.constprop.119
     2.64%  knights_tour_om  libc-2.19.so         [.] __memmove_ssse3_back                                                                         
     1.48%  knights_tour_om  libc-2.19.so         [.] malloc_consolidate
```

You application spends all it's time allocating and freeing memory. While there are some report that [`malloc` is is not fully locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706466/how-does-malloc-work-in-a-multithreaded-environment), it doesn't seem to parallelize nicely either.

It doesn't need much further investigation to figure out that this is caused by copying the `visited` and `path` vectors for each iteration. Fortunately DFS has the nice property, that you don't necessarily need to do that, you can reuse the state and restore it:

```
visited[n] = 1;
path.emplace_back(n);
count += continue_tour(g, path, visited, depth+1,remain-1, cb);
visited[n] = 0;
path.pop_back();
```

However, for the parallel loop, you need to make working copies for each thread, so you need to make a separate path for this case with the original behavior.

This small change already brings down the serial runtime from 22 s to 2.65 s. Further with 2 threads it goes down to 2.0 s. There is a speedup, but it's not so good - why? To illustrate that, I used 4 threads (on a large-enough system). Here is the execution of the application over time recorded with [score-p](http://score-p.org), shown in [Vampir](http://vampir.eu).

[image]

Red is actual work, blue is a implicit barrier, meaning the threads are idling. There always seem to be either 3 or 1 active thread. The reason is simple: Most of the position on the board have either 4 or 2 neighbors, but one of them is already visited so this loop iteration completes instantly. So the actual work is in either 3 or 1 iteration of the loop. That is a particularly bad match for 2 threads. With 3 threads, the runtime goes down to 1.7 s

Note: All times with gcc 5.3 on an E5-2690 @ 2.90 GHz no turbo. No care was taken to compensate for variance in runtimes.

Considering that a single loop exposes very bad parallelism for that problem, you might be tempted to nest parallel loops. I encourage you to try it, but I don't think that will work out well. I would think that tasks work well in this context, because tasks can spawn other tasks. So you can spawn each recursive step as a task and let the OMP runtime figure out a good scheduling. But make sure to limit it up to a certain `depth`, so that tasks do not get too short.

I want to stress the importance of using tools: Trying to figure out performance issues without performance analysis tools is like figuring out bugs without a debugger. `perf` is readily available for Linux and in it's basic form extremely simple to use. Yet it is very powerful (although advanced usage can have some pitfalls).

An additional remark: With OpenMP it is often worthwile to try different compilers. For instance with the (fixed) tasking code, gcc does not scale anymore beyond 4 threads, while the intel compiler / omp runtime provides a speedup even up to 24 threads.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed analysis. I separated out the parallel levels where I copy path and visited and the sequential levels where I mutate them. The OpenMP version now takes only slightly more CPU time than the non-OpenMP version. The new code is at https://gist.github.com/jmoy/2151e6d7070a6ce18aa9298fbe050062

Comment: @JyotirmoyBhattacharya move the `omp parallel`/`omp single` outside of the recursion. I'm not even sure what the semantics for nested task/parallel/single woudl be. It does mess with the tasking runtime.

Comment: BTW: While, with gcc it still doesn't scale well beyond 4 threads for the small example, with the intel compiler / omp runtime scales well even to 24 threads.

Comment: Thanks again. Moving the `parallel/single` out of the recursion improves runtimes here by about 10%.