# Memory sharing between C++ threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm new to threading in C++, and I'm trying to get a clear picture about how memory is shared/not shared between threads. I'm using `std::thread` with C++11.
From what I've read on other SO questions, **stack** memory is owned by only one thread and **heap** memory is shared between threads. So from what I think I understand about the stack vs. the heap, the following should be true:

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class Obj {
public:
    int x;
    Obj(){x = 0;}
};

int main() {
    Obj stackObj;
    Obj *heapObj = new Obj();
    thread t([&]{
        stackObj.x++;
        heapObj->x++;
    });
    t.join();
    assert(heapObj->x == 1);
    assert(stackObj.x == 0);
}
```

forgive me if I screwed up a bunch of stuff, lambda syntax is very new to me. But hopefully what I'm trying to do is coherent.
Would this perform as I expect? And if not, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The premise is a bit wrong. Stack memory is **not** thread local, and it **can** be shared between threads.

Comment: Please see this link for a more detailed answer: http://candrews.net/blog/2011/07/understanding-c-0x-lambda-functions/  - because you used `[&]`, all variables are by reference, so both counters will be 1. If you used `[=]`, your asserts would succeed.

Comment: @juanchopanza my bad, I'm aware that the thread-local has a specific meaning (although I'm not entirely sure what it is), so I changed my question. Is that what was wrong with the "premise"?

Comment: what is wrong is that stack memory isn't owned by one thread, it can be accessed by an arbitrary number of threads.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Memory is memory.  An object in C++ occupies some location in memory; that location may be on a stack or on the heap, or it may have been statically allocated.  It doesn't matter where the object is located:  any thread that has a reference or pointer to the object may access the object.  If two threads have a reference or a pointer to the object, then both threads may access it.

In your program, you create a worker thread (by constructing a `std::thread`) that executes the lambda expression you provide it.  Because you capture both `stackObj` and `heapObj` by reference (using the `[&]` capture default), that lambda has references to both of those objects.

Those objects are both located on the main thread's stack (note that `heapObj` is a pointer-type object that is located on the main thread's stack and points to a dynamically allocated object that is located on the heap).  No copies of these objects are made; rather, your lambda expression has references to the objects.  It modifies the `stackObj` directly and modifies the object pointed to by `heapObj` indirectly.

After the main thread joins with the worker thread, both `heapObj->x` and `stackObj.x` have a value of `1`.

---

If you had used the value capture default (`[=]`), your lambda expression would have *copied* both `stackObj` and `heapObj`.  The expression `stackObj.x++` in the lambda expression would increment the *copy*, and the `stackObj` that you declare in `main()` would be left unchanged.

If you capture the `heapObj` by value, only the pointer itself is copied, so while a copy of the pointer is used, it still points to the same dynamically allocated object.  The expression `heapObj->x++` would dereference that pointer, yielding the `Obj` you created via `new Obj()`, and increment its value.  You would then observe at the end of `main()` that `heapObj->x` has been incremented.

(Note that in order to modify an object captured by value, the lambda expression must be declared `mutable`.)

Comment: If "memory is memory", what is all this about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665419/do-threads-share-the-heap

Comment: @MichaelDorst:  Each thread has its own stack, yes.  Only the thread that owns the stack may allocate memory on that stack.  So, in your program, both the main thread and the worker thread have their own, independent stacks.  There is nothing preventing a thread from sharing with another thread a pointer or reference to an object that it allocated on its own stack, though.  That's exactly what you do here:  The main thread creates an `Obj` object on its stack, then shares a reference to that object with the worker thread.  Both threads then have access to that object.

Comment: Oh, okay that makes much more sense.

Comment: The accepted answer to that question states that "each thread has a private stack."  This is true, but _private_ means "only the thread that owns the stack can create and destroy objects on it."  It does not mean that "no other thread can access this memory."

Comment: By the way sharing objects on stack to other threads is a bad practice. Objects on stack live until the scope is closed. It's possible to get into a situation when an object got already destroyed, but you're still trying to work with it from another thread. It's better to copy or move heap references, unless you're absolutely sure the thread that stores an object won't progress further before other threads get rid of the stack reference.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with James McNellis that `heapObj->x` and `stackObj.x` will be `1`.

Furthermore, this code **only** works because you `join` immediately after spawning the thread.  If you started the thread and then did more work while it runs, an exception could unwind the stack and suddenly the new thread's `stackObj` is invalid.  That is why sharing stack memory between threads is a bad idea even if it's technically possible.

Comment: Thanks for warning me, but what you said doesn't really make sense to me. What exactly is "unwinding the stack" and why would that occur?

Comment: When a C++ program throws an exception, the runtime calls the destructor of each object in the current stack frame, then pops the frame and repeats the process until the exception is caught.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331316/what-is-stack-unwinding