# Passing data to threads using pthreads (in C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

**Hello everyone,**

Here is the situation, I have two sets of threads, Mappers, and Reducers

**Mappers** parse a text file and send individual words with there line numbers to a reducer thread based on a hash function

**Reducers** have a fixed buffer size and place each word in that buffer to a single list

I have Mappers and Reducer threads into separate Pthread arrays

```
For example:

[Step 1]  For the word "example" Mapper thread produces a hash value of 3
[Step 2]  Mapper thread puts "example" and its line number in the 4th 
          reducer's threads (0,1,2,3) buffer
[Step 3]  Reducer thread #4 will place "example" with its 
          line number to the list
```

Please inform me if this is not clear.

**The Problem**
 I can not figure out how to pass information from the mapper thread to the appropriate user thread so Step 2.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can do this ?

I hope my description is clear enough however I can share some code if it helps.

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352249/memory-sharing-between-c-threads

Comment: you could use condition variables to design a solution

Comment: it is almost consumer producer problem. you can solve it using thread-safe queue-s

Comment: What is wrong with existing MapReduce algorithms? E.g, QtConcurrent is an easy-to-use library that contains beside Threading also MapReduce algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to share data between threads. Your example suggests that you need some kind of pipeline. It means one thread push data into a shared data structure while the destination thread will pull data from the same structure. This data structure can be a vector or a list protected by a lock. It is also possible to use a lock free mechanism (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684121(v=vs.85).aspx). You can read more about pipelines here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg663538.aspx