# Starting one delayed job in Rails creates two processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Initially I have no process for delayed jobs(as indicated by htop), then when I run the command `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start` I got one delayed job worker, as indicated by files in tmp/pids. However htop indicates now that there are two processes, as shown in the picture below. [image]

So why is this happening? The other delayed job consumes memory where I don't have much of it!, however its TIME+ is zero, so it didn't consume time, so what does this means ?

Comment: What type of the problem you are trying to solve? Let's start with that

Comment: The problem is that the other process consumes resources, specifically RAM memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess these are actually not two processes but **two threads of a single process**. You can hide threads by typing the capital `H` key in `htop`. If you'll see just one line then, you'll prove that it's a single process.

Delayed job probably has some master thread that governs the worker threads (or just the single worker in your setup), watches the queues and runs the workers if needed. Threads [share most of the memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11909332/1544012) so I rather don't think the resources consumption issue comes from the two lines in `htop`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed typing H showed only one delayed job process, so it's like you said =)