# pthread_mutex_lock causes deadlock

Tags: c, locking, pthreads

I am using the above code to increment a counter using 2 threads, which independently take the mut lock and increment counter. I am facing a deadlock after the threads enter this function.

```
 pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

 void *increment_counter(void *counter_addr)
{
    int max = MAX_COUNTER_VALUE;
    int iter;
    int counter;

    for(iter=0;iter< max ;iter++)
   // LOCK  
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    counter++;
    // UNLOCK 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    return NULL; 
}
```

Could anyone please tell me where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: probably you wanted `int* counter = counter_addr` and `++*counter`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to lock the mutex `max` times, then increment `counter` and release it once.

Try:

```
for(iter=0;iter< max ;iter++)
{
  // LOCK  
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
  counter++;
  // UNLOCK 
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}
return NULL;
```

Comment: Ohh.. That was a bad programming error.. thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 3):

That is maybe what you tried to do:

```
int max = MAX_COUNTER_VALUE;
int iter;
int counter;
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *increment_counter(void *counter_addr)


{

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);    
  for(iter=0;iter< max ;iter++)  
       counter++;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
  return NULL; 
}
```

- 2 or more threads share only global scope data or data located on the
  heap(`malloc`).
- 2 or more threads do not share variables defined on the stack this
  data is unique to each thread and there is no need to lock it.

You are welcomed to read [in the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665419/do-threads-share-the-heap)  what is shared and what is not shared etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a principle, the same thread should not lock a mutex more than once and that's what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

lock initialization is very important. If you don't initialize your locks to the right value your code breaks. One method for initializing your lock is the following:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Also you can do this task dynamically by using the following code:

```
int rc = pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
assert(rc == 0); // always check success!
```

Beside lock initialization, you should check for the return code of `pthread_mutex_lock` to see if it fails or not as if it fails, multiple thread can enter the critical section. For this purpose, you can use a code similar to this which checks for the return code of `pthread_mutex_lock`:

```
// Use this to keep your code clean but check for failures
// Only use if exiting program is OK upon failure
void Pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) {
int rc = pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
assert(rc == 0);
}
```