# What does the underscore suffix in PyTorch functions mean?

Tags: python, pytorch

In PyTorch, many methods of a tensor exist in two versions - one with a underscore suffix, and one without. If I try them out, they seem to do the same thing:

```
In [1]: import torch

In [2]: a = torch.tensor([2, 4, 6])

In [3]: a.add(10)
Out[3]: tensor([12, 14, 16])

In [4]: a.add_(10)
Out[4]: tensor([12, 14, 16])
```

What is the difference between

- `torch.add` and `torch.add_`
- `torch.sub` and `torch.sub_`
- ...and so on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*You have already answered your own question that the underscore indicates in-place operations in PyTorch. However I want to point out briefly why in-place operations can be problematic:*

- First of all on the PyTorch sites it is **recommended to not use in-place operations** in most cases. Unless working under heavy memory pressure it is **more efficient** in most cases to **not use in-place operations**.
  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#in-place-operations-with-autograd
- Secondly there can be problems calculating the gradients when using in-place operations:

  > Every tensor keeps a version counter, that is incremented every time
  >   it is marked dirty in any operation. When a Function saves any tensors
  >   for backward, a version counter of their containing Tensor is saved as
  >   well. Once you access `self.saved_tensors` it is checked, and if it is
  >   greater than the saved value an error is raised. This ensures that if
  >   you’re using in-place functions and not seeing any errors, you can be
  >   sure that the computed gradients are correct.
  >   *[Same source as above.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#in-place-operations-with-autograd)*

Here is a shot and slightly modified example taken from the answer you've posted:

***First the in-place version:***

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([2, 4, 6], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)
adding_tensor = torch.rand(3)
b = a.add_(adding_tensor)
c = torch.sum(b)
c.backward()
print(c.grad_fn)
```

***Which leads to this error:***

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c38b252ffe5f> in <module>
      2 a = torch.tensor([2, 4, 6], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)
      3 adding_tensor = torch.rand(3)
----> 4 b = a.add_(adding_tensor)
      5 c = torch.sum(b)
      6 c.backward()

RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad has been used in an in-place operation.
```

---

***Secondly the non in-place version:***

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([2, 4, 6], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)
adding_tensor = torch.rand(3)
b = a.add(adding_tensor)
c = torch.sum(b)
c.backward()
print(c.grad_fn)
```

***Which works just fine - output:***

```
<SumBackward0 object at 0x7f06b27a1da0>
```

---

So as a take-away I just wanted to point out to carefully use in-place operations in PyTorch.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=underscore), Methods which end in an underscore change the tensor **in-place**. That means that no new memory is being allocated by doing the operation, which **in general** [increase performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/470683/458274), but [can lead to problems and **worse** performance in PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#in-place-operations-with-autograd).

```
In [2]: a = torch.tensor([2, 4, 6])
```

**tensor.add()**:

```
In [3]: b = a.add(10)

In [4]: a is b
Out[4]: False # b is a new tensor, new memory was allocated
```

**tensor.add_()**:

```
In [3]: b = a.add_(10)

In [4]: a is b
Out[4]: True # Same object, no new memory was allocated
```

Notice, that the operators `+` and `+=` are also [two different implementations](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/720c7b1e2c9580fa897110abca3a41ae676174da/torch/tensor.py#L256). `+` creates a new tensor by using `.add()`, while `+=` modifies the tensor by using `.add_()`

```
In [2]: a = torch.tensor([2, 4, 6])

In [3]: id(a)
Out[3]: 140250660654104

In [4]: a += 10

In [5]: id(a)
Out[5]: 140250660654104 # Still the same object, no memory allocation was required

In [6]: a = a + 10

In [7]: id(a)
Out[7]: 140250649668272 # New object was created
```

Comment: Do you have any PyTorch source for this statement: ***"in-place [...] operations [...] can increase the performance significantly [...] you should therefore prefer the in-place method"*** ? As far as I know quite the opposite is the case for PyTorch - use of **in-place** operations in PyTorch is strongly discouraged in most cases. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#in-place-operations-with-autograd

Answer (score 0):

In PyTorch, the ends with an underscore, a convention in PyTorch that indicates the method will not return a new tensor but will instead modify the tensor in place. For example,  `scatter_`.

https://yuyangyy.medium.com/understand-torch-scatter-b0fd6275331c

Comment: This answer adds nothing to the existing answers.